# 'e+08' (don't suppress 0) notation in columns with S-specifier

Tags: tables, siunitx, pgfplotstable

for symmetry reasons in a large table I want the scientific format with 2 digits (i.e. e+08). By default it suppresses the 0.

Here is what I do:

```
 \documentclass[]{article}

 \usepackage{siunitx}


 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
 \begin{center}
 \footnotesize
 \def\fix#1{\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\mathrm{e+}}#1}
 \sisetup{output-exponent-marker = \mathrm{e},exponent-product = {},retain-explicit-plus,retain-zero-exponent,table-format=+1.4e+2}
 \begin{tabular}{lSS}
 Sample & {$\mu_1 [Pa]$} & {$\alpha_1 [-]$} \\ \hline
 {Isotropic $10\%$ MREs} & 1.5030e+09 & \fix{4.2384e+00} \\ 
 & 6.7175e+10 & 8.4376e-01 \\
 & 6.7175e+08 & 8.4376e-01  \\ \hline 
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \caption[]{Scientific notation $e+9$, but for symmetry reasons I would like $e+09$}
 \label{tab:example}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

That is the output:
[image]

Many thanks for your help!
Gerlind

Comment: Workaround: Change column type from `SS` back to `rr` and `8.4376e-01` to `8.4376e$-$01` (twice), then use `\multicolumn{}{}{}` for header cells to center them.

Comment: Currently, not an answer but 'not doable using the `siunitx` code'. I'm working on v3, and I guess I can (should) cover such things. However, I'd say 'do not do this': in a table column, numbers should be comparable and so I'd have `4.23840`/`0.84376`/`0.84376` here

Comment: @JosephWright, your comparison is nicer where possible, but if you've got more than 2-3 orders of magnitude difference you would either need some very wide columns or you start losing significant figures.  I would however suggest that if you're comparing numbers that differ but orders of magnitude you're unlikely to need>~3sf in the mantissa.  Complete counter-example -- a table of physical constants.

Comment: @ChrisH Column of unrelated numbers is different, but I'd still expect proper typesetting (`$\times 10^{<exp>}`) so not an issue. If an experiment makes values differing by the amount you suggest, something very odd is going on, normally

Comment: When is the v3 supposed to be ready?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind using `pgfplotstable` you can have some fun with mantissa and exponent expressions and get pretty close. And as a bonus table entering is slightly easier and aligning is apparently happening automatically (didn't check extensively).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,pgfplotstable,booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}% put your installed version no.
\pgfplotstableset{mycol/.style={
        sci,
        sci zerofill,
        sci precision=4,
        sci generic={
            mantissa sep={e\pgfmathparse{####1<0?"-":"+"}{\pgfmathresult}},
            exponent={%
            \pgfmathparse{abs(####1)<10?0:}\pgfmathresult%
            \pgfmathparse{int(abs(####1)}%
            \pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}%
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/sample/.style={string type,column name=Sample},
columns/mu/.style={mycol,column name={$\mu_1$ [\si{\pascal}]}},
columns/a/.style={mycol,column name={$\alpha_1 [-]$}},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{
sample mu a
{Isotropic $10\%$ MREs} 1.5030e9  4.2384
{}                      6.7173e10 8.4376e-1
{}                      6.7173e8  8.4376e-1
{}                      5.1232154654e7 0.0000124564e-12
{}                      1 2
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, you can have different alignment options, I just didn't bother.

Comment: Great but massive and complicated package as I never used it before. I need to keep `caption`and `label`, I also use `multirow`in the final more complicated table. What about keeping the `tabular`environment and use `newcolumntype`to define what you did in `pgfplotstableset`? Is this possible? So far, I used `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\begin{pgfplotstablecoltype}[#1]}r<{\end{pgfplotstablecoltype}}}`and then in the table `\begin{tabular}{lL{sci,sci zerofill,sci precision=4}L{sci,sci zerofill,sci precision=4}}`. But I don't get the `sci generic`part working, could you help me with this?

Comment: @GerlindSchubert You don't need anything complicated just put the typesetting inside a table as you would do with `tabular`. Then you are done. This package goes through every cell and adjusts the entries such that the desired outcome is placed in the table. If you have difficulties you can always update your question and we can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Following up to answer 1 I want to add what I finally did. The final table is more complicated than the suggested one in the question, and is using more features of the `pgfplotstable`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{rotating}   
\usepackage[bf,footnotesize]{caption}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
% To increase space of some rows in tables, especially needed before and after \hline
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut
% pgfplot setup
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}% put your installed version no.
\pgfplotstableset{
mysci/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci precision=4,sci sep align,sci generic={mantissa sep={e\pgfmathparse{##1<0?"-":"+"}{\pgfmathresult}},exponent={\pgfmathparse{abs(##1)<10?0:}\pgfmathresult\pgfmathparse{int(abs(##1)}\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}}}},
myfixed/.style={fixed,precision=4,dec sep align,fixed zerofill}
}       
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/sample/.style={string type,column type = l,column name=Sample},
columns/strain/.style={int detect,column type/.add={|}{},column name={$\varepsilon [\%]$}},
columns/mu1/.style={mysci,column type/.add={|}{},column name={$\mu_1$ [\si{\pascal}]}},
columns/a1/.style={mysci,column name={$\alpha_1 [-]$}},
columns/mu2/.style={mysci,column name={$\mu_2$ [\si{\pascal}]}},
columns/a2/.style={mysci,column name={$\alpha_2 [-]$}},
columns/mu3/.style={mysci,column name={$\mu_3$ [\si{\pascal}]}},
columns/a3/.style={mysci,column name={$\alpha_3 [-]$}},
columns/mu/.style={myfixed,column type/.add={|}{},column name={$\mu$ [\si{\MPa}]}},
columns/r2/.style={myfixed,column type/.add={|}{},column name={$R_2$}},
columns/norm2/.style={myfixed,column name={$||\cdot ||_2$}},
every head row/.style={after row=\B, after row=\hline},
every last row/.style={after row=\B, after row=\hline},
every row no 0/.style={before row=\T},
every nth row={4[-1]}{after row=\B, after row=\hline},
every nth row={4}{before row=\T},
]{
sample strain mu1 a1 mu2 a2 mu3 a3 mu r2 norm2
\multirow{4}{1.5cm}{Pure Rubber}    40  3.0648e+05  1.5311e+00    7.5072e+02        1.5310e+00  -1.6977e+02  -8.8141e+00    0.2359   0.999986       0.011948
{}                                                  25  3.5423e+05  1.3275e+00      1.5690e+00      3.1398e-10  3.6224e-14          9.8203e-01      0.2351   0.999921   0.010659
{}                                                  15  3.4674e+05  1.3299e+00      7.6212e+02      1.2622e+01  1.4052e+00      9.7551e-01      0.2354  0.999660    0.008762
{}                                                  10  3.0004e+05  1.2792e+00  -6.3089e+04 -1.8889e-07 5.3477e+03      1.8277e+01      0.2408  0.998891        0.008090
\multirow{4}{1.5cm}{Isotropic $10\%$ MREs}  36      9.6811e+05      5.8200e-01          -1.3654e-02 -3.0302e+01  8.3622e-11  4.9200e+00  0.2817  0.999868  0.037122
{}                                                                  25      1.2535e+06      4.4717e-01          1.2331e+02  1.2547e-10      3.9909e-13      3.9848e+00  0.2803  0.999500  0.033976  
{}                                                                  15      -3.6086e+05     -1.4653e+00 9.8794e-07      3.5771e-09      1.2296e-09  1.7867e-07      0.2644  0.998287  0.025398 
{}                                                                  10      -8.2465e+04     -5.7995e+00     7.9359e+01  2.2204e-14  8.9302e-01      3.7158e-09  0.2391  0.996939    0.017356 
}
\captionsetup{width=0.9\textwidth}
\caption{Identified model parameters of \textit{Ogden Model}}
\label{ogden}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

The final output:
[image]