# Zero exponent with explicit plus in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Is it possible to have an explicit + in front of a zero exponent in scientific notation using `siunitx` package? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot,
    retain-explicit-plus,
    retain-zero-exponent}

\begin{document}
\num{1.52e+0}
\end{document}
```

This code outputs something similar to what I would obtain with `$1.52 \cdot 10^0$` while I would like to have the same output as  `$1.52 \cdot 10^{+0}$`.

Comment: First question: Why? What does that mean? are you really talking about exponents here or is this something from chemistry? Do you need that more than one time? Should it be automatical? What about 10e+1?

Comment: I need this to be automatic, I've got a table with a lot of numbers in scientific notation like this, some of them have a zero exponent and, just for a matter of symmetry, I would like them to have a plus in front of the zero. I can't do 10e-1 because my numbers are in scientific notation, e.g., 1.58e+02, 6.06e-11...

Comment: you mean like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166059/e08-dont-suppress-0-notation-in-columns-with-s-specifier/166805#166805

Comment: Yes, quite the same! The only difference is that I don't want the 1.52e+0 notation, but 1.52 \cdot 10^{+0}.

Comment: Then instead of the `e` in the `mycol` style you can add `10^{....}` for the formatting.